# How to create new feature based on clustering result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm still a beginner in machine learning and I want to know how to code this situation based on python and machine learning (clustering).

I have data like:

```
id      Column1    duration(seconde)    column3
1       aaa        20                   bbb
2       ccc        01                   ddd
3       eee        150                  fff
4       ggg        25                   hhh
```

I want to group my data according to the duration column value and create new column containing a category name based on duration cluster.  I want to get this result:

```
id      Column1    duration(seconde)    column3      NewColCategorie
1       aaa        20                   bbb          Cat2 
2       ccc        01                   ddd          Cat1
3       eee        150                  fff          Cat3
4       ggg        25                   hhh          Cat2
5       iii        175                  jjj          Cat3
```

Comment: Are you applying a clustering model or just making clusters based on specific range of values?

Comment: I want to apply clustering but i don't know how to programme it. with the number of centroids =3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do clustering you can use sklearn's KMeans Clustering function - [sklearn.cluster.KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) with `n_clusters=3` and other parameters as default. This will give you 3 clusters. After you have trained your model you can use the `.labels_` attribute of the trained model to classify every example. You can do this in the following way:

```
>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
...               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
>>> kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
>>> kmeans.labels_
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

To create a new column based on category cluster you can simply add the `kmeans.labels_` array as a column to your original dataframe:

```
>>> df['categories'] = kmeans.labels_
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, is another way to use clustering for creating a new feature.
We pass the input_data to `fit_predict` and store the result in new col_name.

**Note:** just remember that need to standardize data before performing clustering.

````
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, max_iter=500, init="k-means++", tol=0.001)
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])

X["cluster"] = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
X["cluster"] = X["cluster"].astype("category")
```
````